# geoNear mongoose include items without coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query using geoNear:

```
      Organisation.collection.aggregate([
                {  
                  $geoNear: {
                    near: { 
                          type: "Point", 
                          coordinates: [
                                       parseFloat(fromLocation.lng),  
                                       parseFloat(fromLocation.lat)
                    ]},
                    spherical: true,
                    distanceField:'distance',
                    distanceMultiplier : 0.001609
                }
            }]
```

How do I include the items without a coordinate value?

nearSphere did this but it did not let me include the distance field in the result.

Comment: im very new to mongodb but i am currently using the exact same feature. I would image it wouldn't return results without coordinates as it wouldn't be within the boundaries of the query. perhaps make a separate call to get the ones without the coordinates and merge the two

Comment: This is what I'm doing now but it's a bit annoying. I thought that you might be able to use something like $ifNull before the GeoNear.  The thing I find most strange is that $near works.  Perhaps it's the difference between an aggregate and a find

Comment: try nearSphere with find